# weird delegate behavior in C#

Tags: c#, delegates, functional-programming

So, I have the code which is responsible for Lagrange polynomial calculating. This code is heavily using delegates (fn_result is declared as `delegate float fn_result (float x)`. The `multiplier(x)` **is** properly calculated despite using recursion; however, trying to calculate `polynom(x)` provides a stack overflow exception. Please could someone tell me why it's so? (Note: polynom(x) is initialized:)

```
fn_result polynom = x => 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i != Lagrange_node_points.Length; i++)
{
    fn_result multiplier = x => Lagrange_node_points[i].Y;
    for (int k = 0; k != Lagrange_node_points.Length; k++) // p[k] cycle
        if (k != i)
            multiplier = x => (multiplier(x) * (x - Lagrange_node_points[k].X) / (Lagrange_node_points[i].X - Lagrange_node_points[k].X));
    polynom = y => (polynom(y) + multiplier(y));
}
```

Comment: Because to calculate `polynom(y)`, you first calculate `polynom(y)`?

Comment: `fn_result multiplier = x => Lagrange_node_points[i].Y;` is your intension `i` or `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly as @Eoin says, but both `multiplier` and `polynom` are in fact infinite.

Test this example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
  Func<int,int> f = x => x * 2 + 13;
  f = x => f(x) + 1337; // Calling itself, not the original function
  int res = f(1); // Stack overflow!
}
```

Comment: Isn't line 4 in your code called lazy evaluation in functional programming? Anyway, I'll try & remake my code. Thanks!

Comment: @user2112311 Exactly, you are welcome :) Delegates are very powerful, but with great power comes great responsibility!

Answer (score 3):

You have a infinite recursive call at this line.

```
polynom = y => (polynom(y) + multiplier(y));
```

Comment: The line `multiplier = x => (multiplier(x) * ...` DOES calculate properly. Either I have a very deep but finite recursion or I lack functional programming understanding.

Comment: @user2112311 I do doubt that, `multiplier` is just a pointer, at execution it would create an infinite recursion as well. It is not referring to it's previous definition as your code seems to imply.